# CUDA Out of Memory Error When Training a Large Language Model on Single GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, gpu

I'm trying to fine-tune a large language model called Bloom, which has approximately 7 billion parameters, on my machine equipped with two NVIDIA RTX A5000 GPUs. However, I'm encountering a CUDA out-of-memory error when attempting to train the model on a single GPU. I've provided the relevant code snippets below for context.

**Problem Description:**
Here's how I'm loading the model

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"  # I'm using GPU 0
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM

our_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    "bigscience/bloom-7b1",
    load_in_8bit=False,
    device_map="auto",
)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bigscience/bloom-7b1")
```

My training arguments are configured as follows:

```
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="bloom7b-finetuned-LoRA-for-Bengali",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    push_to_hub=True,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
)
```

And here's how I'm initializing the Trainer:

```
import torch
# import torch.nn as nn

# Set requires_grad=True for model parameters
for param in our_model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = True

our_model.to(device)
train_dataset = datasets[0]["train"]
eval_dataset = datasets[0]["test"]

# Train the model using multiple datasets
trainer = Trainer(
    model=our_model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    data_collator=data_collator,
)
```

Issue: When I attempt to train the model using this configuration on a single GPU (RTX A5000), I encounter the following error:

```
OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1.91 GiB (GPU 0; 23.68 GiB total capacity; 0 bytes already allocated; 360.06 MiB free; 0 bytes reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to address this CUDA out-of-memory error and successfully train my large language model on my two RTX A5000 GPUs. I'm open to optimizing my code, adjusting hyperparameters, or using any relevant techniques to make the training process more memory-efficient.

Comment: I am not sure, may be Adapters help.